# Issue connect to SQL Server 2000 from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2000

I am using a Winforms C#, .Net Framework 4.0 application and I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2000 using `Data.SqlClient`. Database and app are running on the same server machine.

Before, I ran app on 2 other servers successfully.

My connection string in config is:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True;"
```

but a 3rd server causes an error:

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=3998; handshake=0; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=10000; "

Then, I changed the connection string to

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

and I get a new error

> A transport-level error has occurred during SSPI handshake. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)

Update: I tried using the udl file to create the connection string and put it into the config file but there is still error

So what am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I fixed this issue when replace sqlclient by OLEDB lib

Comment: Did you try to use Integrated security = SSPI ? it works for Oledb and sqlclient provider

Comment: I tried using SSPI but still error

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True;"

This may be correct try to close your connection after you open

Comment: Can you explain more detail?

Comment: as you can see in the error "The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections"

Comment: https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/30/connection-timeout-expired-pre-login-handshake/ you can read about this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not missing anything. Your connection string looks good to me.

ConnectionString="Data Source=xyz;Initial Catalog=xyz;Integrated Security=True;

May be due to any reason the connection was placed using Named Pipes instead of Shared Memory. Shared Memory is the default option for local SQL connection so SqlClient could not recognize the connection was local, and placed through Named Pipes over TCP. Result is connection was refused or not connected.

I am not sure but please check you server name, it should be qualified domain name or IP address. If you specify it by the hostname or "." or "(local)", SqlClient should recognize the local connection, and you should not see the error.

Comment: I tried using the udl file to create the connection string and put it into the config file but there is still error

Comment: Try to test connection in VS Server explorer with the details and parameter you have. Once DB connection is established. You can copy and paste connection string from there. Let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Sorry, server can not install VS

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through this problem and nothing I found anywhere helped, so I thought I'd share the solution that helped me.

Turns out my client had used "username@domain.com" as their login instead of just "username". Looks like there is some functionality internal to excel that tries to authenticate the user via that domain, and thus, the connection times out without a response. Don't create logins with "@domain.com" in SQL Server.

Hope this helps someone in future.